# How to test deployed web applications

Tags: php, linux, testing, authentication

We've build a web application with an update tool which basically pulls from our versioncontrol server and applies an .sql script to the database.
Per client account we have a separate set of php files + a new database. So client accounts are completely separated from each other.

At the moment because we only have 7-8 client accounts after an update I manually click through a few of the pages to see everything went alright, because the whole application is behind a login I use a dummy account to login.

My question is how can I automate this task in propper way.

I could set up some scripts which curl to each client account with login details of this dummy account but this just seems like a bad to create a dummy account for this purpose + the script would need to know the username/pw for each dummy account.

What's a good way to test web-applications behind a log in?

Comment: Seems like a good fit for [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). It provides a bunch of tools that can be easily integrated to monitor and test your server when you deploy.